# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 23-24: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unicode

I am trying to parse csv that contains the text below text (test.csv)

```
"legalgroup_text"   "Aktiebolag"    "Aktiebolag"    "LGAKTIEBOLAG"
"legalgroup_text"   "Allmän försäkringskassa"   "Allmän försäkringskassa"   "LGALLMAENFOERSAEKRINGSKASSA"
```

I am using encoding `iso-8859-1`, since the file contains swedish character

```
import codecs
import csv

with codecs.open('test.csv', encoding='iso-8859-1') as label_file:
    data = csv.reader(label_file, delimiter='\t')
    for row in data:
        print(row)
```

I am getting error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/mnt/ashraful/PycharmProjects/Test/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    for row in data:
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 23-24: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I also tried with encoding `utf-8`, but getting error

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 25: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: 2nd line, specially `ä` character

Comment: This line `for row in data:`

Comment: You really should migrate to Python 3 if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give up on Python 2 and use Python 3. That by itself (no other changes, I just tested) will fix the issue.

Comment: Why people cling to python 2 and complain about unicode errors is a mystery!

Comment: @tdelaney I have sympathy. Some people do have legit reasons for still using py2. Unicode support ain't one of them, though

Comment: I'm getting this error on python 3

Comment: This does not always fix encoding errors, plus moving to Python 3 isn't always possible or realistic for some environments yet.